# Sencha Touch 2 and PhoneGap for In-App Purchases

Tags: mobile, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am interested in using Sencha Touch 2 but need In-App Purchases... I have seen people say they are using PhoneGap to do this with Sencha Touch 2 but no one has clearly stated how they are combining these technologies. I have searched for hours for a tutorial or other information that is from the last 3 months.

I am using DreamWeaver CS5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the closest thing you are going to get is something like this:

http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap

This is by Sencha (using Sencha Touch v1.1 =) and will at very least explain the technologies etc... used that you are asking about.

Have fun and happy coding!